# How to solve image data response as null in react native when using zoho image fetching api?

Tags: react-native, axios, zoho, zohobooks, apisauce

I got API to get full image URL from zoho inventory. But when I try to run it in react native using axios, It shows data null as API response. When I tried through postman it works well. Below show the API that I had used.

[https://inventory.zoho.in/api/v1/items/{item_id}/image?organization_id=XXXXX](https://inventory.zoho.in/api/v1/items/%7Bitem_id%7D/image?organization_id=XXXXX)

So my question is how can I fetch full image url in react native ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the full image url in react native, you will have to add the response type as arraybuffer or blob to receive the file in the API request. Kindly check if this works for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).